# These constraints are not changing together

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-appwidget

I am quite new to the world of Android app development and have been stuck for days on constraining these together. This is the required output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av9Yx.png)

But this is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c7Br.png)

It would be highly appreciated if anyone could help me understand where I have gone wrong.

This is the code snippet:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AdditemActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_item_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/item_name_edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome_message"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item_name_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/is_urgent_linear_layout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrantTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_item_title_text_view"
        android:hint="@string/add_item_edit_text_hint"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:autofillHints="hi" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/is_urgent_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/save_item_add_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_name_edit_text">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/is_urgent_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/is_item_urgent_text"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/is_urgent_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_item_add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add_item_cancel_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/is_urgent_linear_layout"
        android:text="@string/save_item_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_item_cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/save_item_add_button"
        android:text="@string/cancel_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you for viewing and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and adjust the `padding` or `margin` as per your desire.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".AdditemActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_item_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome_message"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item_name_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="hi"
        android:hint="@string/add_item_edit_text_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/is_urgent_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_item_title_text_view" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/is_urgent_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/save_item_add_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_name_edit_text">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/is_urgent_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/is_item_urgent_text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/is_urgent_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/is_urgent_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_item_add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/save_item_text"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add_item_cancel_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/is_urgent_layout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_item_cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel_text"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/save_item_add_button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem, but you should have seen an error if you tried to build the project.

In the *EditText* for _item_name_edit_text there is a mispelling:

```
app:layout_constrantTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_item_title_text_view"
```

should be

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_item_title_text_view"
```

You are missing the "i" in *constraintTop*. Make that change and you will see your improved layout.